boost::multi_index range based composite key
I am trying to perform a compound range query on a multi index container, and I am having some issues. Let's take the simplest example:

// This is my object
struct Obj {
  int one;
  int two;
  int three;
};

typedef boost::multi_index_container<
  Obj,
  boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
    boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<
      boost::multi_index::composite_key<
        Obj,
        boost::multi_index::member<Obj, int, &Obj::one>,
        boost::multi_index::member<Obj, int, &Obj::two>
      >
    >
  >
> object_multi;

int main() {
    object_multi objects;

    // For example
    objects.insert({1, 1, 3});
    objects.insert({1, 5, 6});
    objects.insert({2, 2, 4});
  
    auto& index = objects.get<0>();
    // get elements where one = [1, 3] AND two [1, 2]
    auto lower = index.lower_bound(boost::make_tuple(1, 1));
    auto upper = index.lower_bound(boost::make_tuple(3, 2));

    for (auto it = lower; it != upper; ++it) 
        std::cout << it->one << ", " << it->two << ", " << it->three << std::endl;
    
  
  return 0;
}

I would expect to only get Obj{1, 1, 3} and Obj{2, 2, 4} which are the only ones that match both search criteria, but that code returns also Obj{1, 5, 6} where two is not <= 2.
What am I missing? Is it possible to achieve what I need?
Thanks in advance.

You've built a "composite key" ordered index.  The index values are:
{1, 1}
{1, 5}
{2, 2}

You then query it for values which are between {1, 1} and {3, 2}.  All values in the index are in that range, because the index checks the first component before checking the second.  Put another way, it's like having the numbers [1.1, 1.5, 2.2] and asking for the ones between 1.1 and 3.2.  They're all in that range.
Based on your comment, you probably thought the index was something that checked each component individually and returned the intersection of the results:
// get elements where one = [1, 3] AND two [1, 2]

But that's not how it works.

Got it, thanks for the clarification. So I guess there's no way of achieving what I want unless I get say all the elements in one index and then filter further right? Basically what I would like to achieve is kinda like a "select from objects where one in (set of numbers) and two in (set of numbers)"

@Santiago that's basically correct.  As a former user of Boost MultiIndex, I would recommend you not use it.  It's complicated and tends to create as many difficulties as it solves.  For your case it'd be easier to just make your own solution.

As discussed in John's answer, you need to perform some intersection work on your side. This is one way to do it:
Live Coliru Demo
#include <boost/lambda2.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/key.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered/unordered_flat_set.hpp>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Obj {
  int one;
  int two;
  int three;
};

typedef boost::multi_index_container<
  Obj,
  boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
    boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<
      boost::multi_index::key<&Obj::one>
    >,
    boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<
      boost::multi_index::key<&Obj::two>
    >
  >
> object_multi;

template<typename Iterator1, typename Iterator2, typename F>
void visit_intersection(
    Iterator1 first1, Iterator1 last1, Iterator2 first2, Iterator2 last2, F f)
{
    boost::unordered_flat_set<
        const typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator1>::value_type*> rng1;
        
    while (first1 != last1) rng1.insert(std::addressof(*first1++));
    
    for ( ; first2 != last2; ++first2) {
        if (rng1.contains(std::addressof(*first2))) f(*first2);
    }
}


int main() {
    object_multi objects;

    // For example
    objects.insert({1, 1, 3});
    objects.insert({1, 5, 6});
    objects.insert({2, 2, 4});
  
    // get elements where one = [1, 3] AND two [1, 2]
    
    using namespace boost::lambda2;
    
    auto [first1, last1] = objects.get<0>().range(_1 >= 1, _1 <= 3);
    auto [first2, last2] = objects.get<1>().range(_1 >= 1, _1 <= 2);

    visit_intersection(
        first1, last1, first2, last2,
        [](const auto& x) {
            std::cout << x.one << ", " << x.two << ", " << x.three << std::endl;
        });
        
  return 0;
}

Output
1, 1, 3
2, 2, 4

